# Securing each service in microservices architecture

Tags: authentication, oauth, microservices

Im planning to use api gateway as main security layer. Then using token relay I'm sending token to microservices and they verify this token. If microservices need to communicate with eachoter they also send token. My friend told me that I'm complicating it more than I should. Should I only use security on api gateway layer? But then it would be hard to verify if user has access to resource in microservice, so I would stay on my way. But maybe I'm wrong and is there any way that is considered a standard?

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors, but read about [Zero Trust](https://www.forcepoint.com/cyber-edu/zero-trust).

Comment: You're not wrong, you're actually adhering to the latest best practice of implementing Zero Trust APIs. You can read more about it here: https://curity.io/resources/learn/implementing-zero-trust-apis/